# Забанили аккаунт разработчка, что делать?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Добрый день. По глупости были забанены гуглом. Вопрос собственно в том, можно ли пересоздать аккаунт через тор браузер, на новом компьютере, и при условии, что не будем заливать на него старые проекты?

Answer (score 9):

С точки зрения правомерности - нет, нельзя. Вам надо добиться от гугла разблокировки старого акка.

С технической точки зрения, если у гугла не будет данных для связывания нового акка со старым (мыло, ip, банковские счета, реальный адрес, приложения, ключ подписи) то это возможно. Но ничто вас не убережёт от повторного бана, если гугл что-то заподозрит.

Comment: Ну это понятн.. Вопрос в том, банит ли гугл за тор?

Comment: @МаксимВоробьёв, мне это неизвестно, но не должен. Использование тора как такового не должно быть противоправным. Просто его, обычно, для неправомерных действий используют. В связи с чем могут проявлять большую внимательность к действиям, через него совершённым.

Answer (score 0):

При использовании ТОР гугл не банит, но стоит быть весьма щепетильными, чтобы не дать гуглу повод хоть как-то заподозрить связь аккаунтов. До тех пор пока таких подозрений у них не будет - будет вам счастье, но если заметят, аккаунт сразу улетает в бан.